# How to disable the welcome page in Keycloak 17

Tags: keycloak

The new distribution of Keycloak that is powered by Quarkus does not have a standalone.xml file in order to achieve this purpose.

How can I disable the path and (if needed) how can I customize this page?

Comment: Hi, did you find out how to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not ... and according to the code repo ... there is no "official" way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to disable the page, but if you have a custom theme like on previous Keycloak versions, you can set it on start-up like this:

```
kc.sh start --spi-theme-welcome-theme=<theme-name>
```

Sorry that I don't answer your main question, would like to post this as comment but i don't have enough reputation :)